# Golang conditional compilation

Tags: go, build, go-build

I've got a trouble with conditional compilation in Go 1.

Here is my test code. Is there anything I misunderstand about the "// +build" constraint and the "-tags" flag?

main1.go

```
// +build main1
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("This is main 1")
}
```

main2.go

```
// +build main2
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("This is main 2")
}
```

when running "go build", I still got compile error

```
$ go build -tags 'main1'
# test
./main2.go:8: main redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ./main1.go:8
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You must follow `// +build XXX` with a blank line.

In my brief search, I couldn't find where/if this is documented. But [the source](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/go/build/build.go?r=2449e85a115014c3d9251f86d499e5808141e6bc#790) clearly calls it out

Comment: It is documented in http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints. Specifically: "To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series of build constraints must be followed by a blank line."

Answer (score 19):

The `// +build` tag, used up to Go 1.17, must be followed by an empty line:

```
// +build main1

package main
```

Starting from Go 1.17, conditional build tags are able to use `//go:build` lines that support boolean expressions instead of the old `// +build` lines.

#### Main improvement

- `//go:build` comment format is consistent with other go directives as `//go:embed`, `//go:generate`, `//go:noinline`, etc.
- the syntax for boolean expressions between build tags is now standardized, using `&&` and `||` operators

#### Syntax comparison

| Expression | `// +build` | `//go:build` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OR | `// +build foo bar` (space-separated) | `//go:build foo || bar` |
| AND | `// +build foo,bar` | `//go:build foo && bar` |
| NOT (unchanged) | `// +build !foo` | `//go:build !foo` |

#### Multiline comments

More complex boolean expressions can make use of parenthesis, whereas before it required multiline comments:

From:

```
// +build foo bar
// +build 386
```

to:

```
//go:build (foo || bar) && 386
```

Additionally, with `//go:build`, multiple directives over more than one line are now disallowed.

#### Automatic formatting

- running `go fmt` on a source file with a `// +build` directive will automatically add the matching `//go:build` one.
- running `go fmt` on a source file with a `//go:build` directive in the wrong place will automatically fix it. So now your issue would be solved by simply running `gofmt -w main.go`

---

Source: [Go 1.17 build constraints draft design](https://golang.org/design/draft-gobuild). (Currently still a draft even if Go 1.17 is officially released)

Answer (score 14):

> [Package build](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)
>
> Build Constraints
>
> A build constraint is a line comment beginning with the directive
>   `+build` that lists the conditions under which a file should be
>   included in the package. Constraints may appear in any kind of source
>   file (not just Go), but they must appear near the top of the file,
>   preceded only by blank lines and other line comments.
>
> To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series
>   of build constraints must be followed by a blank line.

Add a blank line after the build constraint. For example,

```
// +build main1

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("This is main 1")
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Right, you must leave a blank line, not exactly after `// +build XXX` but before `package main` because all the comment lines before the line declaring the package are considered to be the description of the package and parsed by `godoc`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Build Constraints](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) docs:

> To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series of build constraints must be followed by a blank line.