# Can i have custom build flags like os/arch comment directives

Tags: go

In golang I am able to set compiler directives in the first line comment of a file to determine whether the code on that file is included in the build based on OS or arch, e.g

to target windows:

```
// +build windows
```

or non-windows:

```
// +build !windows
```

Is there any way to pass in my own boolean variable at build time to operate in the same way?

The background is that I would like a boolean debug flag which I can pass in to do a debug build, I don't want my debug code included in the normal build.

I currently do something like this:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.Debug=true"
```

but I would prefer to use 1st line comment method particularly as this approach doesn't omit debug code from the build (I presume).

Ideally I want:

*debug-on.go*

```
// +build debug

package debug

func Debug() bool {
    return true
}
```

and *debug-off.go*

```
// +build !debug

package debug

func Debug() bool {
    return false
}
```

**Update RE duplicate**
I accept the related question has the same subject matter but it's really not a duplicate question, that is a question from somebody who already knew about this feature but is struggling with implementation.

My 2 cents is that it seems the equivalent of "What language to people speak in France?" vs "How do you say 'This is not a duplicate' in French?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang conditional compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646531/golang-conditional-compilation)

Comment: @Adrian: Different question, different answer. The answer to the [Golang conditional compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646531) question was to add a blank line following build contraints. That's not an answer to this question.

Comment: @Adrian: The official words: "That's because the proof is in the answers. If the question looks the same, but the answers aren't solving the asker's problem, that is not a dupe – that is a legitimate new question."

Comment: @peterso It demonstrates how to use build tags, which is the answer to this question. You're welcome to find a more appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [Command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> Go is a tool for managing Go source code.
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go command [arguments]
> ```
>
> [Compile packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
> ```
>
> Build compiles the packages named by the import paths, along with
>   their dependencies, but it does not install the results.
>
> The build flags are shared by the build, clean, get, install, list,
>   run, and test commands:
>
> ```
> -tags 'tag list'
>   a space-separated list of build tags to consider satisfied during the
>   build. For more information about build tags, see the description of
>   build constraints in the documentation for the `go/build` package.
> ```

---

> [`go/build` package: Build Constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)

---

For example, in source,

```
// +build debug
```

At runtime, for `build`, `clean`, `get`, `install`, `list`, `run`, and `test` `go` commands,

```
$ go install -tags='debug'
```