# `formatOnSave` adds a `go:build` tag at the top of the file on save

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Here's the problem.

I want to format my golang files when they get saved, so I have this in my user settings (JSON) file.

```json
    "[go]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    },
```

But as a side effect, whenever I save a file that has a `// +build integration` tag at the very top of it, VSCode ends up adding `//go:build integration` to the top of the file, in addition to formatting the file.

Any clues how I can disable this behavior?

Comment: I guess that's just the way gofmt behaves. But I don't see what the problem is. gofmt does the right thing and replaces the old version with the new version of that build comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67937234/9208887

Comment: The fmt tool is changing the file to the correct go1.17 format: https://go.dev/doc/go1.17#gofmt

Comment: _"Any clues how I can disable this behavior?"_ You shouldn't. Be grateful that `gofmt` replaces your deprecated code with the new, preferred version.

Answer (score 1):

I stand corrected that this is indeed the latest, better behavior. Thanks JimB and The Fool.

Comment: this is not an answer, make a comment or edit your question